# How to place the Green snap/glue points on a visio symbol

Tags: microsoft-visio-2013

I have created my own symbols in Visio 2013.  How do I place the Green Snap/Glue points on the lower left and right of a symbol?

I have tried to used the "X" command, seems to set two points but they do not snap/glue to an existing Visio Equipment Rack that has snap/blue points.